# redis (StackExchange.Redis) publish performance is poor?

Tags: performance, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use redis pub/sub to transfer data between apps with high velocity (25000 message per second).

I have tested it as below:

**topology**:

1 publisher, 1 subscriber and redis server. All are hosted in the same pc.

**pc hardware**:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) I7-4578U CPU@3.00GHz
Memory: 16.0GB

**code**:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
while (_started)
{
    //db.PublishAsync(RawMessagesCapturedMsg.TopicGroupName, redisValue);
    db.Publish(RawMessagesCapturedMsg.TopicGroupName, redisValue);
    totalRedisMsg++;
    if (totalRedisMsg % 10000 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("totalRedisMsg: {0} @ {1}, time used(ms): {2}",
            totalRedisMsg, DateTime.Now, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
sw.Stop();
```

**results:**
[image]

As shown in the results, it will take about 6 second to publish 10k messages.

I want to confirm that **is it the actual performance of redis (or StackExchange.Redis)? Or there is something wrong with my test?**

**Update:**

According to the accepted answer, I found out the reason is my message size is too large (300kB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A things to check:

1. What is the CPU load? Is it full? If not, you're probably stuck on bandwidth or latency.
2. How much is the size of the message? Multiply it by the transfer
   rate you see, is it comparable to the bandwidth you (expect to)
   have?
3. What is the ping to the Redis instance? Maybe round trips are taking much time. In that case you can use many threads with many connections to increase throughput.

I had a benchmark at my hand that I used to answer another question. And in Java (lettuce client library) I have this results for 1 thread, local cpu i5-6400, remote cpu E5-2603 v4, 0.180ms ping to remote and the message is "hello".

```
Benchmark              (address)   Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
LettuceThreads.pooled     socket  thrpt    5  35699.267 ±  706.946  ops/s
LettuceThreads.pooled  localhost  thrpt    5  28130.801 ± 9476.584  ops/s
LettuceThreads.pooled     remote  thrpt    5   3080.115 ±  422.390  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared     socket  thrpt    5  41717.332 ± 3559.226  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared  localhost  thrpt    5  31092.925 ± 9894.748  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared     remote  thrpt    5   3920.260 ±  178.637  ops/s
```

Compare it to the hardware you have, maybe it will help you evaluate your library performance. Note, how performance drops 10x for remote, even knowing that CPU is slower 2x, that is a lot.

And the following is for 16 threads. So, as you see, bigger number of threads  may help at least get the throughput despite the latency.

```
Benchmark              (address)   Mode  Cnt       Score       Error  Units
LettuceThreads.pooled     socket  thrpt    5  123846.426 ±  2926.807  ops/s
LettuceThreads.pooled  localhost  thrpt    5   83997.678 ± 31410.595  ops/s
LettuceThreads.pooled     remote  thrpt    5   31045.111 ±  2198.065  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared     socket  thrpt    5  218331.662 ± 17459.352  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared  localhost  thrpt    5  182296.689 ± 52163.154  ops/s
LettuceThreads.shared     remote  thrpt    5   30803.575 ±  2128.306  ops/s
```

Comment: According to your answer,  I find out that my message size is very large (300KB). I haven't notice it before I read your post. You save my day, thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it helped! Could you please add 'performance' tag to your question?